# HTML 5/PHP Multi file upload field

Tags: php, html

I am trying to build a simple HTML5 multi file uploader.

```
<input type="file" name="listingimages[]" multiple>
```

I would like to modify the code I've come up with below so it works for listingimages[] instead of $_FILES. I've tried a couple of different variants but I can't seem to get it to get the files in listingimages[]. My script below works fine for each singular upload field but I need it to work for each individual upload array as well.

```
$files = $_FILES;

foreach ($files as $field_name => $val) 
{  
        $target_path = "../../uploads/listing/files/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename($files[$field_name]['name']); 
        move_uploaded_file($files[$field_name]['tmp_name'], $target_path);
        $_POST[$field_name] = $files[$field_name]['name'];  
}
```

What i would like to do is modify the above to work for only listingimages[] and not all $_FILES.

Comment: Why are you assigning the name of the file to a post param? Generally speaking, you shouldn't modify the superglobals.

Comment: I did this because this is just for a personal script, and im just quickly emailing the post array to myself when files are uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just modify the foreach:

```
foreach($_FILES['listingimages'] as $field_name => $val) {
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but i gave that a try and it didn't work for me, still nothing is uploaded.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($_FILES);`?

Comment: array(2) { ["listing_hero_image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } ["listingimages"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "IMG_0237.JPG" [1]=> string(12) "IMG_0224.JPG" } ["type"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" [1]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(45) "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php2DWwvq" [1]=> string(45) "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php2EhBIa" } ["error"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(0)

Comment: Ahh. Bad mistake that I always make! I never remember to remove the `[]`. Code modified in my answer. It should work now.

Comment: I tried that and nothing uploads :( I think the rest of the code must need further modification

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the answer after some further research:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['listingimages']['name']); $i++) {
    $target_path = "../../uploads/listing/files/";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['listingimages']['name'][$i]); 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['listingimages']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path);
}
```